# RegExp To Search For Array Of File Extensions

Tags: regex, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am using this syntax to search for one file extension, how can I alter it to search for 2?

```
Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.pattern = ".mdb"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
```

Comment: `.Pattern = ".mdb$|.accdb$"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe character `|` to split two possible match values.  For example, if you want to match against an Access database and an Excel spreadsheet, you would use this:

```
Dim objRegExp As Object
Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegExp.pattern = "\.mdb$|\.xls$"
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
```

The `$` indicates that the pattern has to be found at the end of the string being checked.  The `.` will also be treated as a special character so you need to escape it, using a `\` backslash.

Comment: Missed it in my comment above, but `.` should be escaped: `\.`.

Comment: I missed it too... Fixed now though, thanks for the heads up